# Ubuntu terminal, Gnome terminal, Python will not let me type lowercase a.

Tags: gnome

I need to fix my terminal, in command mode lowercase a will not type, same with Python. any help would be awesome.

Comment: Can you add the result of `bind -p | grep $'\x61"'` please?

Comment: I'm very new to all of this, can you go through the steps for me.

Comment: Just type it in a terminal - it doesn't have any "a"s in it ;) It doesn't do anything malicious - just lists any mappings of `readline`  that include lower case "a" (represented by hex ASCII value 61, since you can't type an actual "a")

Comment: I typed "bind -p I grep $'\x61"'  it gave me "\C-a": beginning-of-line.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the self-insert mapping for the `a`-key has gone missing from your readline bindings - you *should* have seen

```
$ bind -p | grep $'\x61"'
"\C-a": beginning-of-line
"a": self-insert
```

You should be able to fix it in the current terminal session by issuing the bind command

```
bind $'"\x61": self-insert'
```

however for a **persistent** fix you will need to track down how exactly the key is getting unbound - check for a custom `~/.inputrc` and also check if any modifications have been made to the system-wide `/etc/inputrc` e.g. using

```
diff -s /etc/inputrc /usr/share/readline/inputrc
```

Comment: Thank you thank you, so much . I will look in to ~/. inputrc

Comment: how would I go about to fix the problem  through the whole system, my python will not let me type lower case a either.